# Check for custom interface in the beforeExecute and afterExecute always fails

Tags: java, executorservice

I have an extended ThreadPoolExecutor with overridden beforeExecute and afterExecute methods. So my class kind of looks like this

```
class MyExtendedExecutor extends ThreadpoolExecutor {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r , Throwable t) {
        if(r instance of MyInterface)
            // cast r to MyInterface and call a method available in MyInterface
            // then something in MyExtendedExecutor does something with the return value
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        if(r instance of MyInterface)
            // cast r to MyInterface and call a method available in MyInterface
            // then something in MyExtendedExecutor does something with the return value

    }
}
```

and this is always failing although I've made sure that all the Runnables that I submit to the executor implement MyInterface, basically

```
class MyTask implements MyInterface, Runnable {
    ...
    ...
}
```

and doing

```
myextendedExecutor.submit(new MyTask())
```

then why is the instanceof check failing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) you have to call `super` and r is actually an instance of `Future` from which you can retrieve your `MyInterface` object, not your `MyInterface` directly.

```
 class MyExtendedExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   // ...
   protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
     super.afterExecute(r, t);
     if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
       try {
         Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
       } catch (CancellationException ce) {
           t = ce;
       } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
           t = ee.getCause();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
       }
     }
     if (t != null)
       System.out.println(t);
   }
 }
```